# SharePoint 2013 DOM dialog object

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript

I'm using SP2013 and I am trying to refresh one of many list web parts on a page with the Manual Refresh button displayed for each list.

The current display view has four lists associated with it each with a Manual Refresh button displayed for each.

I am trying to refresh via JavaScript.  Async Update is enabled as is Show Manual Refresh Button in the respective web parts.

My code works as long as the List Settings>Advanced Settings> Dialogs is set to NO. A full page view.

So, for example, `document.querySelectorAll("#ManualRefresh")` returns a usable object.  So, the code to refresh for a specific web part looks as follows:

```
var myelement-document.querySelector("#WebPartWPQ6");
var refresh=myelement.querySelectorAll("#ManualRefresh");
myrefresh[0[.click();
```

When in the console I run `document.querySelectorAll("#ManualRefresh")` I am returned an object which in my case has 4 elements since I have four ManualRefreash buttons on the page.

However, when Dialogs is set to Yes the `document.querySelectorAll("#ManualRefresh")` returns a Null object.

Seems I need to use something other than "document" in document.querySelectorAll statement to grab the DOM element from the dialog vs. the document. That is my assumption anyhow.

How do I access the dialog object vs. the document object and then use the queryselector as above modified to use a dialog vs. a page?  If my nomenclature is wrong by all means correct me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog object shoulg be iframe element in html, and you could get the element in iframe with this script:

```
document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.document
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868032/javascript-how-to-change-elements-content-inside-a-page-when-using-iframes-us